# Postfix cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/private/server.key: disabling TLS support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, postfix-mta

I installed a postfix mail server. But it is wrong when I use thunderbird to login a user.
This is configuration.

**Postconf -n:**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 20000000000
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
message_size_limit = 200000000
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = stack.daolicloud.com
myhostname = mail.stack.daolicloud.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

**dovecot -n:**

```
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS release 6.4 (Final) 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
    ssl = yes
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/server.key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

And this is log:

```
 dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: Can't load private ssl_key: Key is for a different cert than ssl_cert
dovecot: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling
dovecot: pop3-login: Fatal: Can't load private ssl_key: Key is for a different cert than ssl_cert
dovecot: master: Error: service(pop3-login): command startup failed, throttling
postfix/smtpd[13891]: warning: cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/private/server.key: disabling TLS support
postfix/smtpd[13891]: warning: TLS library problem: 13891:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
postfix/smtpd[13893]: warning: cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/private/server.key: disabling TLS support
postfix/smtpd[13893]: warning: TLS library problem: 13893:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
postfix/smtpd[13894]: warning: cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/private/server.key: disabling TLS support
postfix/smtpd[13894]: warning: TLS library problem: 13894:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
postfix/smtpd[13895]: warning: cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/private/server.key: disabling TLS support
postfix/smtpd[13895]: warning: TLS library problem: 13895:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:331:
```

I think the `pem` and `key` file were wrong. So I generate this files again followed by [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html). But it still goes the same error. Any ideas? Could someone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to check if the cert and key match use this,

```
(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem | openssl md5 ;\
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/private/server.key | openssl md5) | uniq
```

If you get more than one identifier, then you key and cert don't match.

Just create a new one;

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/server.key
```

Cheers!

Comment: I love StackOverflow and you.

Comment: create a new one? but wasn't the original .key required to create the PEM? I gave my .crt (generated thanks to my .key) to my CA root so they provided me the .pem, how can I re-issue a new key without consequences? I don't understand

Comment: You have an error there, and it's very likely that is on your side, maybe you have the same name for different keys/csr on different paths.
If you aren't sure create a new one, and send the csr to your certificate provider so they reply a new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this error on Centos 8, Postfix 3.3.1 running SELinux I tried all the above and I knew my certs and chains were correct as apache was loading them correctly.

I was seeing the following error under the original error:

```
warning: TLS library problem: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
```

Turns out that the certs *must be* in the:

```
/etc/ssl/certs
```

directory - even though I had the right chcon on them. Thought this might help anyone else as it was very frustrating. I'm not sure why Postfix couldn't load them from the httpd directory.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ark74's answer from [someone's blog](https://root.bg/tutorials/cannot-get-rsa-private-key-from-file-disabling-tls-support/), on ubuntu the check command for the snakeoil certificate is:

```
(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem | openssl md5 ; openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key | openssl md5) | uniq
```

If you get two hashes, then the certificate needs to be regenrated:

```
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```